# Selenium not executing with default chrome user profile

Tags: python, windows, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Cheers, I can not execute my selenium python script with the default chrome profile (aka the one I am connected to with email), The code works just fine in guest mode (The profile that selenium defaults to when running the script) but It refuses to even execute when adding the following line :
`options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Faycal\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")`
After running the code I am prompted with the following browser error : [image: Browser prompting after running the script]

There are no errors in the terminal and the script does not even run, I tried adding \ at the end of the path, I tried changing the profile by adding another chromedriver option but nothing seems to work.
Hopefully someone can help, thanks alot and have a nice one.

Edit 1: Here is the code I am trying to run :

````
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.color import Color

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
    url = "https://portail.if-algerie.com/login"
    user_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Faycal\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data' 

    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
    options.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+user_data_dir)
    options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')


    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
    while(True):
        try:
            driver.get("https://portail.if-algerie.com/login")
            break
        except:
            driver.refresh()
            continue

    driver.implicitly_wait(15)
    email = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="email")
    password = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="password")
    login_button = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="login")


    email.send_keys("mail")
    password.send_keys("pwd")
    time.sleep(2)
    login_button.click()

    time.sleep(2)
    link = driver.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value="Tests et Examens")
    link.click()
    register_link = driver.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value="S'inscrire")
    register_link.click()
    time.sleep(2)```
````

Answer (score 4):

You have to add two arguments in order to achieve the desired result. The first is the one you already added, and the second is the "profile-directory".

```
# The r means that the string is to be treated as a raw string,
# which means all escape codes will be ignored.
user_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Faycal\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data' 
# User's data path
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+user_data_dir)
# Profile directory
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
```

As for the script of your first edit, the problem is that you used a `while` loop, which is a bad practice in this case. You should use the `WebDriverWait` class of `Selenium` instead, and the conditions of the `expected_conditions`.

Some examples of such conditions are the following.

**`presence_of_element_located:`**
An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible. locator - used to find the element returns the WebElement once it is located.

**`element_to_be_clickable:`** An expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.
Element is either a locator (text) or an WebElement.

With that being said, a login function should look something like this:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time


def login():
    try:
        timeout = 20 # Number of seconds before timing out.
        user_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Faycal\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data'
        options = uc.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
        options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
        options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=' + user_data_dir)
        options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
        driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get(r'https://portail.if-algerie.com/login')
        email = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "email")))
        email.send_keys("mail")
        password = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password")))
        password.send_keys("pwd")
        login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "login")))
        login_button.click()
        time.sleep(50)
    except TimeoutException as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    login()
```

In the above snippet, `Selenium WebDriver` waits up to 20 seconds before throwing a `TimeoutException` unless it finds the element to return within the above time. `WebDriverWait`, by default, calls the `ExpectedCondition` every 500 milliseconds until it returns successfully.

[image]

Comment: This fixed the browser error i.e the appropriate profile is opened when running the code but .. that's about the script isnt excuted beyond that point ..it's just an empty browser(loaded with the appropriate profile)

Comment: To address this issue, you need to provide us with the rest of your code.

Comment: I edited the post adding the code

Comment: The answer was updated as well. If you found it helpful, you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Sadly the edit did not solve the issue, I am still facing the same problem : the browser opens with the default profile but no code is running beyond that point.

Comment: I included a screenshot in the initial answer, which shows that the code is working properly. Hence, it must be a problem on your side. You can try running the code on a virtual machine to confirm it.